# How to set up a static route to allow PS Vita remote play to PS3 through a second router?

Tags: networking, osx-lion, ps3, ipfw, static-routes

I'm trying to get my PS Vita to connect to my PS3 through my home network rather than the PS3's wireless access point (mainly because of the PS3's weak signal). My Mac (OS X 10.8.2) is sharing its internet connection from en0 (ethernet) to en1 (wireless), to which my PS Vita is connected. En0 is a LAN that connects to the router and subsequently the PS3.

**PS vita** (wireless) → (en1) **Mac** (en0) → (wired) **Router** (wired) → **PS3**

I thought a static route or two would be a possible solution. That or a combination of static routes and pf port forwarding. I've been reading and trying various methods for a few days and have just ended up confused.

Is this possible? If so, what rules/routes would be required?

Answer (score 0):

Just incase there are other people that are in the situation I was in, I thought i'd post how I managed to solve my problem.

I never managed to get the hang of static routes or the subsequent attempts at using NAT via osx. (Something I will dive into at a later date I hope, as it's pretty interesting). But I did managed to solve my problem with wifi range and remote-play lag.

Using an old router (WRT-54g v2) coupled with DD-WRT firmware, I configured the router into an AP (Access Point). This allowed me to share the primary router's subnet to both devices. I set each device its own static ip, as in the beginning I was experiencing a lot of IP clashes.

Once I could connect to the internet on the Vita reliably, I deleted the Vita from the "registered devices" list on the ps3. Before re-registering, i'd made sure that it was connected to the AP upstairs.

After I was able to start Remote play on the PS3 using the 'Connect via Internet' option (on the Vita). With full network signal (and minimal lag), I can now enjoy Shadow of the Colossos, ICO and Tokyo Jungle without having to disturb anyone downstairs :D

I guess the steps where:

**1>** Find a compatible router for use with DD-WRT custom firmware.
Read up on what firmware you need and how to install it by going through the Peacock Thread: 
http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=51486 .

**2>** Configure your router to suit your needs. Again most of the information I found in the aforementioned thread. This helped too: 
http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Repeating_Mode_Comparisons

**3>** Set static ip's for your ps3 and PS-vita.

**4>** (If already registered with PS3) Delete registered Vita on the PS3's 'Remote Play' list.

**5>** Re-registered while connected to new AP, Client Bridge, Repeater Bridge, etc.

**6>** Start up 'Remote Play' and press 'Connect Via Internet'.

**7>** Cross Fingers..

Anyways I hope this helps anyone struggling with crappy ISP provided routers and 'Lead Lined' walls such as myself..

Soba.

Comment: This worked for me perfectly! I set me PS3 to a DMZ on my Netgear Router while having it directly wired. I gave it a static IP along with my Vita, then connected the Vita to my DD WRT router, registered it for Remote Play, and voila.